# how to ignore all files with same extension in directory

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I need to fix this part of my `.hgignore`

```
win/*.opensdf
win/*.sdf
win/*.suo
win/*.filters
win/*.user
win/*.db3
```

seems like it doesn't work as it wrote here.

win is at root. And even `*.db3` doesn't work for me, only `(?i).db3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is win at your root? Otherwise you will need `*/win/*.ext`

Comment: win is at root. even `*.db3` doesn't work for me, only `(?i).db3`

Comment: And, you are trying to ignore something like `win/file.db3`? This pattern will not work for `win/dir/file.db3`, just to clarify

Comment: Also, do you have syntax: glob? I think it defaults to regular expressions otherwise.

Comment: no, I didn't add glob. `win/dir/file.db3` works but I need all .db3

Comment: *.db3 works for me. It drills to all directories. I would suggest adding the syntax: glob on the line above it though